# How do associations change inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, associations

When you build a model association with lets say belongs_to :user, how does that change the inheritance?

Does the user class now have access to all the methods of the class being linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Association doesn't affect inheritance in any way. It just adds several methods to `self` to simplify querying.

All added methods are listed [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference)